# Is there a way to display \cosec in Mathjax?

Tags: mathjax

While I can add `\sec` to MathJax, I am unable to add `\cosec`. Could the experts here please help me if/when free?

[image]

Comment: `\operatorname{cosec}`

Comment: @egreg Very grateful to you  Could you please add it as an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: No, this is a mixture of off-topic and duplicate.

Comment: Note: Questions about MathJax a usually not on topic here. However, because `\cosec` also wouldn't be defined with plainTeX or LaTeX and the answer `\operatorname{cosec}` would also help using LaTeX, this question maybe could be on-topic.